# Dynamically adding a select box based on input from another select box

Tags: jquery

I am building a form which will be used to enter the result of a student into a school database. Now the school has 2 sections for the 5th till 8th standard and 1 for the 9th till 10th.

Here is what i want to do, there should be a select box where the user can select the standard for which he wants to enter data, if the selected standard is within the limit of 5th to 8th then another select box needs to be dynamically added which will have the option to select "Section A" or "Section B". If the user selects 9th or 10th grade then no section select box should be there.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow - please take some time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) - especially the section on What questions to ask here - this is not a *get code for free* site ... the idea is that you post an issue and poeple attempt to help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Since you haven't shown any of your html markup or attempts at writing the JavaScript for yourself I'll just give you a bare-bones jQuery solution and leave it to you to match up to your actual html.

In my opinion the easiest way is to implement your requirement is to include both select elements in the html markup and just hide and show the second one as applicable. (Not only is this easier than dynamically adding and removing the element, it has the added advantage of leaving your form accessible for the occasional user who has JavaScript disabled.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $section = $("#section").hide();
    $("#standard").change(function() {
        var val = +$(this).val();
        if (val >= 5 && val <= 8)  // assume option elements have value="5", etc.
            $section.show();
        else
            $section.hide();
    });
});
```

Further reading: http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: thanks for the idea i didnt even think about it that would work just fine

Answer (score 0):

The following jQuery lets you watch for a change on the select element, and get the currently selected element:

```
$(function() {
    $("#sections").change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value > 8) {
           //do stuff
        } else {
           //do other stuff
        }
    });
});​
```

You can then use the $("selector").show() and $("selector").hide() methods to display/show some other element.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<label for="std">Std</label>
  <select id="std">
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
  <span id="gradeContainer" class="hide">
    <label for="grade">Grade</label>
    <select id="grade">
      <option value="0">--Select--</option>
      <option value="1">Grade A</option>
      <option value="2">Grade B</option>
    </select>
  </span>
```

CSS

```
.hide { display : none }
```

JS

```
    $(function() {
        $("#std").change(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if(parseInt(value,10)>8) {
                $("#gradeContainer").show();
            } else {
               $("#gradeContainer").hide();
            }
        });

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a little of all of your ideas and ended up with this, it works and thought i would just post the end result

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$("#std").change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(parseInt(value,10)>8) {
            $("#gradeContainer").hide();
        } else {
           $("#gradeContainer").show();
        }
    });

});//]]> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="std">Std</label>
<select id="std">
  <option value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<span id="gradeContainer" class="hide">
<label for="grade">Grade</label>
<select id="grade">
  <option value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option value="1">Grade A</option>
  <option value="2">Grade B</option>
</select>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```